# Is there a way to fix this

Tags: javascript, arrays

hi im making this like mini silly program where you have 3 arrays two arrays are filled with four numbers they have to simmilar numbers so i made this for loop to check the similarity between the two arrays and log them into the 3rd array but it prints 2 arrays instead keep in mind am a begiiner [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w87Vh.png)  yea again im a beginner so go easy on me and if you can explaining your code not just the answer and this might trigger you proffesionals sorry if it does :)

i tried everrything i tried rewriting the loop i tried modifying it where it pushes j and i but that didnt work

```js
let onArr = [90, 66, 97, 55]
let twoArr = [90, 77, 55, 80]
let threeArr = []

for (let i = 0; i < onArr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < twoArr.length; j++) {
    if (onArr[i] === twoArr[j]) {
      threeArr.push(onArr[i])
      console.log(threeArr)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: To "loop once" is essentially the same thing as not having a loop at all.

Comment: Also your code should be posted here, as text, not as a picture of text.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through one of the arrays and check if the value is in the other array as well. Checking if a value is in array can be done using the array method **includes**. If true then add the item to your 'third array'. Like this:

```js
let oneArr = [90, 66, 97, 55];
let twoArr = [90, 77, 55, 80];

function getSame(arr1,arr2) {
  let arr3 = [];
  for (let item of arr1) {
    if (arr2.includes(item)) {
      arr3.push(item);
    }
  }
  return arr3;
}

console.log(getSame(oneArr, twoArr));
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you `console.log` each time you find a match (of which there are two). You want to log after you find all the matches, so move the log to be after the loops

```js
let onArr = [90, 66, 97, 55]
let twoArr = [90, 77, 55, 80]
let threeArr = []

for (let i = 0; i < onArr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < twoArr.length; j++) {
    if (onArr[i] === twoArr[j]) {
      threeArr.push(onArr[i])
    }
  }
}
console.log(threeArr)
```

Comment: @laithmaree np, we all started at the bottom at some point